# Facing issues while integrating core-data in chat application

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, socket.io, nsfetchedresultscontroller

We are facing issues while integrating coredata with our chat application. Please help us to resolve the issue. We tried to figure out each issue individually but sometimes it gets fixed and then shows up randomly. We are tring to fix it from last 1 week.

**Our setup stack**

We are using sockets library to for real time chatting. To persist the data we are using core-data. Our application is supporting iOS 8 and above so we can't use PersistenceContainer so to workoround this we are using BNRCoreDataStack [url: https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack] which is similiar to what PersistenceContainer does.

Also to display chat we are using IGListKit and we have created viewModels to avoid sending mutable coredata objects to IGLIstkit as IGListkit works fine with immutable model. Also we have used this setup to create our own viewModels [url: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Guides/Working%20with%20Core%20Data.md]

**issues we are facing**

1] Constraint validation failure

2] FetchResult controller crash issue

crash-log:

```
2018-07-19 21:41:36.515153+0530 Toppr Doubts[62803:2359707] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/UITableView.m:2012
2018-07-19 21:41:36.517093+0530 Toppr Doubts[62803:2359707] [error] error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (60) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (50), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (60) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (50), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

3] Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'lastMessage' between objects in different contexts

Below is our CoreDataModel, we are not using any abstract entity for Message as we came to know this could cause lot of performance issues.

[image: core-data-model-image]

**Session Entity**

We are creating object in fromJSON method and setup is same for rest of the entities. Also I am sharing LastMessage Entity to show the way we are integrating relationships, again same for others

```
public class Session: NSManagedObject {
     class func fromJSON(_ json: JSON, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Session? {


    if let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Session", in: moc) {
        // Object creation
        let object = Session(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: moc)

        object.internalIdentifier = json[kSessionIdKey].int64Value

        if let date = json[kSessionStartedOnKey].dateTime as NSDate? {
            object.startedOn = date
        }

        if let date = json[kSessionEndedOnKey].dateTime as NSDate? {
            object.endedOn = date
        }

        object.statusType = SessionStatus(rawValue: json[kSessionStatusKey].stringValue).map { $0.rawValue } ?? SessionStatus.none.rawValue
        object.stateType = SessionState(rawValue: json[kSessionStateKey].stringValue).map { $0.rawValue } ?? SessionState.none.rawValue

        if let ratingDict = json[kSessionRatingKey].dictionaryObject {
            if let rating = ratingDict["student"] as? Int {
                object.rating = rating
            }
        }

        object.subjectID = json[kSessionSubjectKey]["id"].intValue

        // Subjects are already stored need to fetch and assign
        let subjectFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Subject> = Subject.fetchRequest()
        subjectFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "internalIdentifier == %d", Int64(json[kSessionSubjectKey]["id"].intValue))

        do {
            if let subject = try moc.fetch(subjectFetchRequest).first {
                object.subject = subject
            }

        } catch let erroe as NSError {
            Logger.log.error(error)
        }

        // Student Object initialisation
        if json[kSessionStudentKey] != JSON.null {
            if let student = Student.fromJSON(json[kSessionStudentKey], moc: moc) {
                object.student = student
            }
        }

        // Tutor Object initialisation
        if json[kSessionTutorKey] != JSON.null {
            if let tutor = Tutor.fromJSON(json[kSessionTutorKey], moc: moc) {
                object.tutor = tutor
            }
        }

        // LastMessage Object initialisation
        if json[kSessionLastMessageKey] != JSON.null {
            if let lastMessage = LastMessage.fromJSON(json[kSessionLastMessageKey], moc: moc) {
                object.lastMessage = lastMessage
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        return object
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

**LastMessage**

```
public class LastMessage: NSManagedObject, Message {

  class func fromJSON(_ json: JSON, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> LastMessage? {

    if let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LastMessage", in: moc) {
        let object = LastMessage(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: moc)
        object.id = json[kMessageIdKey].intValue
        object.body = json[kBodyKey].stringValue
        object.type = MessageType(rawValue: json[kTypeKey].stringValue) ?? MessageType.none

        object.doubtTag = json[kDoubtTagKey].stringValue

        if json[kAttachmentKey] != JSON.null {
            if let attachment = Attachment.fromJSON(json[kAttachmentKey], moc: moc) {
                object.attachment = attachment
            }
        }

        if let date = json[kSentOnKey].dateTime as NSDate? {
            object.sentOn = date
        }

        if json[kSentByKey] != JSON.null {
            if let sentBy = SentBy.fromJSON(json[kSentByKey], moc: moc) {
                object.sentBy = sentBy
            }
        }

        object.deliveryState = DeliveryState(rawValue: json[kDeliveryStateKey].stringValue) ?? DeliveryState.none
        object.sessionId = json[kSessionIdKey].intValue
        return object
    }
    return nil
  }

}
```

**Get User State**
Helps us fetch data for subject and live chat.

```
static func getUserState(completion:@escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

    SocketManager.sharedInstance.send(eventName: .userState) { (response) in
        guard !response.isError() else { return completion(false) }


        // Coredatastack
        guard let coreDataStack = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack else { return }
        let wmoc = coreDataStack.newChildContext()

        // Save Subject and Live Sessions
        let subjects = response.result["subjects"].arrayValue.flatMap({ Subject.fromJSON($0, moc: wmoc) })
        let sessions = response.result["live_sessions"].arrayValue.flatMap({ Session.fromJSON($0, moc: wmoc) })

        if sessions.isNotEmpty || subjects.isNotEmpty {
            CoreDataStack.batchUpdate(moc: wmoc, completion: {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("didUpdateUserState"), object: nil)
                completion(true)
            })
        }
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

**Get Previous Session**
Helps us fetch data for inactive chats. We are getting problem in this while storing sessions

```
static func getPreviousSessions(isLoadingMore: Bool, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool,_ isMore: Bool)->Void) {
    guard let coreDataStack = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack else { return }
    let wmoc = coreDataStack.newChildContext()

    var sessionID = 0

    // TODO: - Need to implement last sessionID from CoreData
    if isLoadingMore {
        // Get Sessions with Status == closed order by sessionID asc
        let archiveSession = Session.filterArchivedSessions(moc: wmoc)
        let sortedArchiveSession = archiveSession?.sorted(by: { $0.0.id < $0.1.id })

        // Get last sessionID
        if let lastSessionID = sortedArchiveSession?.first?.id {
            sessionID = lastSessionID
        }
    }

    let request: [String: Any] = [ "last_session_id": sessionID ]

    SocketManager.sharedInstance.send(request, eventName: .getPreviousSessions) { (response) in

        if response.result.isEmpty {
            completion(false, false)
        } else {
            let sessions = response.result["sessions"].arrayValue.flatMap({ Session.fromJSON($0, moc: wmoc) })
            if sessions.isNotEmpty {
                CoreDataStack.batchUpdate(moc: wmoc)
            } else {
                for session in sessions { wmoc.delete(session) }
            }

            if let isMore = response.result["is_more_server"].bool {
                completion(true, isMore)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: tableview-coredata]

In the above image every session is suppose to have one last message and one subject. But as you can see, there are no last messages and some session have subjects as null

**CoreDataStack+Extension**
To Save data directly to Store

```
extension CoreDataStack {
 // This method will add or update a CoreData's object.
 static func batchUpdate(moc: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil, completion: (()-> Void)? = nil) {
    guard let moc = moc, moc.hasChanges else { return }

     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        moc.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    }

    do {
        try moc.performAndWaitOrThrow {
            try moc.saveContextToStoreAndWait()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error creating initial data: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

**NSFetchedResultsController Setup**

```
lazy var archievedSessionFRC: NSFetchedResultsController<Session> = {

    guard let coreDataStack = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack else { return NSFetchedResultsController() }

    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Session> = Session.fetchRequest()

    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "internalIdentifier", ascending: false)]

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "statusType = %@", "closed")

    let archievedSessionFRC = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.mainQueueContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)

    archievedSessionFRC.delegate = self

    return archievedSessionFRC

}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupViews()
    do {
        try archievedSessionFRC.performFetch()

        if let sessions = archievedSessionFRC.fetchedObjects {
            self.previousSessions = sessions
        }
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
extension HomeVC: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch type {
            case .insert:
                if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                     self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                 }
            case .delete:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                }
            case .move:
                if let indexPath = indexPath , let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                     self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
                }
            case .update:
                 if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                }
        }       
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {        
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post code as text not images. Ask one question at a time. Keep your question short and to the point. [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)